# Smallest of margin's between 2 floating divs in webkit

Tags: html, css, webkit, margin

Any css guru want to educate a simpleton on this one?  In Chrome (and I presume Safari as well) I'm getting a small (maybe 1px) margin between 2 floating divs.  Width of the left div is 58% and the right div is 42%.  In Firefox there is no such margin. Haven't tried IE or Opera yet. Using Chrome's dev tool I did see that p has something called -webkit-margin-before and -webkit-margin-after which were set to 1em. I tried overriding that but it doesn't help.  Probably unrelated. Any help?

Link to the page: http://www.audlibri.com

EDIT: confirmed same problem in Opera 11.

Comment: Each browser may round percentages differently; so this is likely the cause of your "margin".

Comment: Does seem to be a rounding issue with the pixels.  Setting the right to `42.1%` in the dev tools seems to remove it.

Comment: Add a doctype and see if that helps.

Comment: IE9 good/bad news.  The margin isn't there, but it is stacking the divs vertically. Edit: IE9 is reading the doc in quirks mode. This might be a doctype issue.  Once I switched to standards mode it looked correct.

Comment: Percentage-based sizes are always a hassle, at least they are when you need them to add up.

Comment: Thanks guys. I added a doctype of html (as per http://diveintohtml5.org/semantics.html) but that didn't help.  I could have a different width for each browser but that's overkill.  I'm going to take the suggest of having the body as my right div's color.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, the best fix to this problem is setting `body { background:#XXX; }` to the same color of one of those columns (`#788081` or `#B7B59B`). Hopefully there's no real need for them to be flush against each other.

Answer (score 0):

It's a sub-pixel rendering problem with percent-based web layouts.

[This short article](http://ejohn.org/blog/sub-pixel-problems-in-css/) by [John Resig](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Resig) (of jQuery fame), explains it very clearly.

It's a little out of date (Jan 2008), but still applicable, I'm sure.